# should I use ace_select_reactor or ace_dev_poll_reactor

Tags: c++, sockets, ace

I dont know which reactor to choose use ace_select_reactor or ace_dev_poll_reactor.
The reactor is used for listening of incoming open connection events on a server which uses unix domain socket

Comment: Just try one and see if it works?

Comment: they both work. but which is better. what are the reasons to use one or the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from:  *Dev_Poll__Reactor.html#*details">http://www.riverace.com/ACE/ace55/html/ace/classACE*_Dev_*Poll*_Reactor.html#_details*

The ACE_Dev_Poll_Reactor uses the `/dev/poll' or '/dev/epoll' character devices to demultiplex events on a given set of file descriptors. Unlike select(),`/dev/poll' and `/dev/epoll' **have no hard-coded limit on the number of file descriptors that may be handled at any given time**. As such, the ACE_Dev_Poll_Reactor can generally handle a much larger number of file descriptors than select() -based reactors.
but I have to notice that's only available certain UNIX platforms